# proof for test of a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

The square of any integer is either perfectly divisible by 4 or leaves a remainder 1 when divided by 4. Any number which on division by 4 leaves a remainder 2 or 3 is not a perfect square. Prove

Comment: Have you tried anything? What part of the question are you stuck on? Also note that this is not a very good test, since it's passed by numbers such as  $5, 8, 12$ and $13$, which are _not_ squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the remainder (regarding division by $4$) of the square, using the computation rule
$$
(a b) \bmod q = 
\left((a \bmod q)(b \bmod q)\right) \bmod q \quad
(a,b,q \in \mathbb{Z})
$$
for taking the remainder, one gets
$$
r = n^2 \bmod 4 = (\underbrace{n \bmod 4}_s)^2 \bmod 4 \\
$$
For the four possible values of $s$ we get these remainders:
$$
r(0) = 0^2 \bmod 4 = 0 \\
r(1) = 1^2 \bmod 4 = 1 \\
r(2) = 2^2 \bmod 4 = 0 \\
r(3) = 3^2 \bmod 4 = 1
$$
thus a perfect square is of the form $4q$ or $4q+1$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the class of the square of a number modulo 4. Hence, it is enough to show that in the finite ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ the only squares are 0 and 1. Compute the square of the four classes $\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3}\}$ and figure out the answer.